# É uma boa prática usar funções virtuais em classes não derivadas?

Tags: c++

Quando eu estava aprendendo C++ li em um livro no capitulo de polimorfismo sobre funções virtuais, que a palavra chave virtual servia para indicar que aquela função ia ser sobreescrita em outra parte do código, desde então passei a adicionar virtual em todas minhas definições de cabeçalho.

Certo dia estava em um projeto do android studio em que eu usava o NDK, quanto recebi um erro semelhante a isso:

> A classe possui funções virtuais, porém não possui um destrutor
>   virtual

Pesquisando sobre este erro logo notei que as pessoas apenas usavam a palavra chave virtual em classes derivadas ou abstratas, porém logo lembrei de ver uma função virtual em uma classe de um projeto da unreal engine 4 que não era sobrescrita de outra classe, então usar funções virtuais em classes não derivadas é correto ou apenas ignorado pelos compiladores desktop? (Obs: uso o MSVC, não me lembro deste erro no g++ também, o android studio usa o clang)

Comment: "desde então passei a adicionar virtual em todas minhas definições de cabeçalho" — isso soa como abuso de funcionalidade, uso sem razão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você mesmo disse, usar palavra chave virtual serve para indicar que a função pode ser sobrescrita em outra parte do código. Então, se você estiver usando a classe de maneira polifórmica, ou seja, se estiver usando um ponteiro ou referência do tipo da classe base para acessar aquela função o programa vai procurar a função correta a ser chamada em tempo de execução. Por exemplo:

```
class Base{
  public:
  virtual void f();
  ~Base();
};

class Foo:
  public Base
{
  ...  //outras declarações
  public:
  void f();
  ~Foo();
};

int main(){
    Base* base = new Foo();
    base->f();  //chama a função f na classe Foo
    delete base;//chama o destrutor de Base 
}
```

Como a função a classe Base não tem um destrutor virtual, o destrutor que é chamado é o de Base, deixando a parte da classe Foo por destruir, e daí entramos no mundo do comportamento indefinido. Então por regra, se uma classe fornecer alguma função virtual (o que significa que ela poderá ser herdada) ela também deve fornecer um destrutor virtual.

E daí você pode se perguntar, porquê em `c++` as todas as chamadas de funções membros não são determinadas em tempo de execução sem que haja necessidade de as declarar como virtuais? A resposta mais simples é que tem a ver com o facto do processo ser um pouco penoso ([link para uma explicação mais detalhada em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)).